# C# Smart-client deployment is not working?

Tags: c#, iis, smartclient

I haven't deployed a smart-client in a very long time, so I may be doing something wrong.  My publish works well, and the app works for me (could be cached?), but my users can't run the app and instead get this error:

```
Can't reach this page 
Make sure the web address XXXXX is correct
```

Also, when I browse the page from the server, IE briefly starts like the app is going to run, but then nothing ever comes up.  The default document is set correctly.

The app works perfectly locally, so I am sure it is an IIS setup issue.

I am just not sure where to go with this.  Can anyone offer a suggestion for troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Industry decided 5 years ago to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues. June Microsoft pushed a security updated that disables TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and now requires clients to use TLS 1.2/1.3.  Most likely this is the issue. Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and see what version of TLS is being used. Default version when not specified in c# depends on a few issues.1) Version of Windows 2) Version of Net 3) IE settings. You may be able to fix issue by opening up an IE and changing the TLS version. IE settings are the default settings when TLS is not specified in c#.

Comment: I just checked and all TLS settings are enabled in IE on the server.  I don't think that's it, though, because it actually ran once about a month ago on this server.

Comment: What version is being used?  The Microsoft Security Update may of been installed recently.  Many companies wait a month or two before installing Windows Updates.

Comment: In IE, versions 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 are all checked.  I don't actually use a certificate with this app and have no experience with TLS.  I've never had to do anything with TLS and smartclients I used in the past, which I have to admit has been a while.

Comment: The app itself is .NET Framework 4.6.

Comment: Uncheck 1.0 and 1.1.  It is possible the server want 1.3, but first try just 1.2.

Comment: I think something's wrong with my manifest file.  Looking at it now.

Comment: I was looking for an easy fix and to prove my theory was correct.  The Manifest I do not think is setting the TLS. Issue can be fixed in c#, but lets prove the theory first.  Since it was working locally I wanted to verify the customers could make same settings changes in IE.

Comment: I had my friend who is a programmer move the app to her server, where he deploys smart clients regularly.  He got the same result.  He is going to take a look at the app this afternoon.  I will report his findings.

Comment: Is it a he or a she?  "her server, where he deploys"

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to say "her server."  I should have said "his server."

Comment: Clear the cache and you can try to browse the website from the iis server to see if the page is still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my organization (actually, the parent organization over my organization) had decided to block the port I was using.  After I convinced them to open the port, all worked as expected.